# Add a filter by date to My Account Orders in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Here is the Function, which enables me to create filter by date fields for WooCommerce orders in frontend (MY ACCOUNT). It's working, but when I choose date when there are no orders, Filter fields disappearing and there is no way to filter again I have to manually remove added parameters from URL.

I want to achieve the following: When there are no orders Filter fields must still be visible to be able to choose different date and also there must appear reset button which will reset the filters.

Here is my current code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_account_orders', 'add_form');
function add_form($has_orders)
{   
    if ($has_orders) {   
        echo 
        '</form>
        <form action="#" method="get">          
        <input type="date" name="start_date">
        <input type="date" name="end_date">
        <input type="submit" value="' . esc_attr__( 'Filter by date', 'your-text-domain' ) . '">
        </form>';       
    }
}
    
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 10, 1);
function custom_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query($array) {
    $start_date='';
    $end_date='';
    if ( isset($_GET['start_date']) && isset($_GET['end_date'])){
        $start_date = $_GET['start_date'];
        $end_date = $_GET['end_date'];
    }
    $array['date_query'] = array(
        array(
            'after'  => $start_date, //start_date 2021-11-16
            'before' => $end_date, //end_date
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    );
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As WooCommerce order query uses [WC_Order_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#date), you need something a bit different:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_account_orders', 'filter_myaccount_orders');
function filter_myaccount_orders($has_orders){   
    if ($has_orders || isset($_GET['start_date']) || isset($_GET['end_date']) ) {
        $start_date = $end_date = ''; // Initializing;
        if ( isset($_GET['start_date']) && ! empty($_GET['start_date']) ) {
            $start_date = esc_attr($_GET['start_date']);
        }
        if ( isset($_GET['end_date']) && ! empty($_GET['end_date']) ) {
            $end_date = esc_attr($_GET['end_date']);
        }

        echo  '</form>
        <form action="#" method="get">          
        <input type="date" name="start_date" value="'.$start_date.'">
        <input type="date" name="end_date" value="'.$end_date.'">
        <input type="submit" value="' . esc_attr__( 'Filter by date', 'your-text-domain' ) . '">';
        if( isset($_GET['start_date']) || isset($_GET['end_date']) ) {
            $myaccount_orders_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) . 'orders/';
            echo '<a class="button reset" href="'.$myaccount_orders_url.'">'.__('Reset').'</a>';
        }
        echo '</form>';       
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_account_orders', 10, 1 );
function custom_my_account_orders( $args ) {
    $start_date = $end_date = '';// Initializing;
        
    if ( isset($_GET['start_date']) && ! empty($_GET['start_date']) ) {
        $start_date = esc_attr($_GET['start_date']);
    }
    if ( isset($_GET['end_date']) && ! empty($_GET['end_date']) ) {
        $end_date = esc_attr($_GET['end_date']);
    }

    if ( $start_date && ! $end_date ) {
        $args['date_created'] = '>='.$start_date;
    } elseif ( ! $start_date && $end_date ) {
        $args['date_created'] = '<='.$end_date;
    } elseif ( $start_date && $end_date ) {
        $args['date_created'] = $start_date.'...'.$end_date;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I just put it and still doing same there is no reset button appearing and whole date filter fields still disappearing when there is no orders on specific dates

Comment: It's working, thank you so much it showed this error while saving:

"Cannot redeclare custom_my_account_orders() (previously declared in ..." 

I solved it. but there is one thing when I click reset it sends me back to /my-account/orders/ and I don't want redirect user must stay on same page when refreshed. ( I am using subaccounts and thats why I need it)

Comment: understood, Thank you so much for Great help!